# Why its 0.0 ELB instances?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have completed successfully the deployment of my rails app to my environment, but when I can see there is 0.0 ELB instances at monitoring dashboard, why is that?

here is my log when I deploy:

```
INFO: Deploying new version to instance(s).                         
INFO: New application version was deployed to running EC2 instances.
INFO: Environment update completed successfully.
```

Currently I only get blank page when visiting my app, I assume that's because I got 0.0 ELB instances

How would I solve this?

Here is a snapshot:

[image]

**EDIT, activity log:**

```
[2015-08-23T17:18:03.570Z] INFO  [18661] - [Application update/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/99_reload_app_server.sh] : Starting activity...
[2015-08-23T17:18:04.993Z] INFO  [18661] - [Application update/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/99_reload_app_server.sh] : Completed activity. Result:
  + service passenger restart
  According to the PID file '/var/app/support/pids/passenger.pid',
  Phusion Passenger Standalone doesn't seem to be running.

  If you know that Phusion Passenger Standalone *is* running then one of these
  might be the cause of this error:

   * The Phusion Passenger Standalone instance that you want to stop isn't running
     on port 80, but on another port. If this is the case then you
     should specify the right port with --port.
     If the instance is listening on a Unix socket file instead of a TCP port,
     then please specify the PID file's filename with --pid-file.
   * The instance that you want to stop has stored its PID file in a non-standard
     location. In this case please specify the right PID file with --pid-file.
  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/nginx_config_healthd.erb:49:in `block in write_nginx_config_file': undefined local variable or method `location_config_filename' for #<PhusionPassenger::Standalone::StartCommand:0x007f7ab$
        from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/erb.rb:863:in `eval'
        from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/erb.rb:863:in `result'
        from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.15/lib/phusion_passenger/standalone/start_command/nginx_engine.rb:120:in `block in write_nginx_config_file'
        from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.15/lib/phusion_passenger/standalone/start_command/nginx_engine.rb:113:in `open'
        from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.15/lib/phusion_passenger/standalone/start_command/nginx_engine.rb:113:in `write_nginx_config_file'
        from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.15/lib/phusion_passenger/standalone/start_command/nginx_engine.rb:41:in `start_engine_real'
        from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.15/lib/phusion_passenger/standalone/start_command.rb:609:in `start_engine'
        from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.15/lib/phusion_passenger/standalone/start_command.rb:80:in `run'
        from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.15/lib/phusion_passenger/standalone/main.rb:50:in `run!'
        from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/passenger-5.0.15/bin/passenger:44:in `<top (required)>'
        from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/passenger:23:in `load'
        from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/bin/passenger:23:in `<main>'
[2015-08-23T17:18:04.993Z] INFO  [18661] - [Application update/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook] : Completed activity. Result:
  Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact.
```

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot? Not sure what you mean by 0.0 instances.

Comment: Kindly have a look above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using enhanced health. Can you click on the dashboard link. You will see a causes button. Click the causes button it will tell you why your environment health is severe. See an example screenshot for locating the causes button here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/elastic-beanstalk-update-enhanced-application-health-monitoring/

Comment: what is enhanced health? causes button does not tell much, it says "ELB health is failing or not available for all instances.
Impaired services on all instances."

Comment: The console currently does not show the instances health... In the meantime you can use DescribeInstancesHealth api from beanstalk using sdk or aws cli. It appears the nginx proxy is not running on your server. Impaired services can mean either proxy or application is not running. Can you click on logs to get snapshot logs from the instances? Then you can see detailed wrote messages.

Comment: Here's how to get logs : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.logging.html

Comment: I saw this in the log: According to the PID file '/var/app/support/pids/passenger.pid',
  Phusion Passenger Standalone doesn't seem to be running. but isn't it started automatically after successfully deploy the app?

Comment: It should be started automatically. Look in /var/log/eb-activity.log

Comment: How did you fix the issue?

Comment: I have created a new env using eb command and terminal, then every thing was correct, its much easier to use eb command line rather than using the online wizard.. at least, this is what I've experienced..

Answer (score 0):

You have 0 instances running and thats why your app is not running. You need to click on EC2 and restart your instance associated with your Elastic Beanstalk.